# Bash script to configure IPTABLES

Tags: iptables, bash, scripting

I am beginner at BASH scripting, I'm trying to write script to configure iptables but it seems something wrong in the first block, Please advise

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "IPTABLE ASSIGNMEN"
echo -e "1.Reject all except one IP\n2.Flush iptables (*Use Carefully_it will remove all the rules from iptables*)\n"
echo -e "Select Number"
read number;
if [[$number == "1"]]; then
        echo "Insert IP\n"
        read ip;
        iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ip -j ACCEPT
        iptables -P INPUT DROP
        iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
fi
```

Comment: the iptables.service now can save settings, on CentOS it is saved on `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. Every time you return `systemctl restart iptables` it will go there to load all the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your support, Actually as you mentioned, I used case statement, also due to the error **$'\r': command not found** , which caused by editor style, I used "*dos2unix filename.sh*" to solve it and run the script "*sudo bash filename.sh*" which worked properly.

```
!/bin/bash
echo "IPTABLE ASSIGNMEN"
echo -e "1.Reject all except one IP\n2.Flush iptables (*Use Carefully_>
echo -e "Select Number\n"
read x;
case  $x in
        "1" )
        echo "Insert IP\n"
        read ip;
        iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -j ACCEPT
        iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ip -j ACCEPT
        iptables -P INPUT DROP
        iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
                ;;
        "2" )
                iptables -F
                iptables -X
                iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
                iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
                iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
                ;;
        * )
        echo "Try Again"
                ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [equality test](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/conditions-in-bash-scripting-if-statements) is incorrect

```
if [ $number == "1" ]; then
```

You need *single* square braces *with* spaces around them.
Double square braces do something a bit different.

Also ...

Get into the habit of using *single* quotes wherever you can.
Linux applies [expansion rules](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html) to literals in *double* quotes.

```
ip=127.0.0.1

echo '$ip'
$ip

echo "$ip"
127.0.0.1
```

If you don't want/need this, use single quotes to make this clear.

Since you're probably going to add *more* options, look into the **case** statement.

```
case $number in 
'1' : 
  ;;
'2' : 
  ;; 
esac
```

Comment: Actually, `[` is an external command (`test`), and `[[` is a `bash` builtin. It can be used for testing conditions, and does not require calling an external program, so it is (in my opinion) a better choice. Also, `case` patterns need to be terminated with `)`, not `:`.

Comment: Thank you Phill for your clarification, and thank you Lacek for your suggestion, I used case statement and its working well.